# Salesforce Territories

Tags: process-builder, territory-management, workflowrule, territory

I'm brand spanking new to Salesforce.  Helping a friend with some of her accounts and I'm learning as I go.

She wants me to find a way to make her assignment rules for her territory fields work.  Right now she is using workflow rules to say when a lead comes from HERE assign it to THIS territory and THIS sales rep.  But something is going wrong.  The fields don't always populate and when they do, they don't always transfer to the territory fields from the LEAD to ACCOUNT to OPPORTUNITY stage...

I started researching and see that workflow rules will no longer be supported by Salesforce, so it would be better to use Process Builder...BUT while researching, I also came across Territory Management and think this would be what they need to use, but unfortunately, the organization doesn't have that enabled.  I need more information or guidance at this point.

QUESTIONS:

Would Territory Management be the best tool to use in this case? If so, how difficult is it to get enabled?

If not, will process builder work? or will I need to go about this a completely different way?

Any resources you can offer will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  How are Territories being handled currently?  Is Territory just a text field or picklist on the Lead and Account objects, or is there more to it than that?

Comment: Since you're new to Salesforce, you should definitely check out the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) for all kinds of tutorial modules, and also be sure to search the Salesforce/Dreamforce channels on YouTube and other website resources to learn more about the features you want to use.

Comment: Thank you. I have been using trailhead but there is so much information and I just didn't know where to start or what my options should be.  I'm not sure if it's a picklist or text field. How do I check? and what do you mean by its there more to it than that?  I would like to answer all your questions, but I'm afraid I'm still very much in the dark.  Thank you kindly for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Territory Management is great for big organizations, but I have a feeling it might be more than you need in this case.  Take a look at **[Lead Assignment Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_assignment_rules.htm&type=5)** instead.  That will get you as far as assigning each lead to a user.

From there, it sounds like you need to assign each Lead to a territory as well. It depends on how you're defining territories now -- e.g., is territory just a text field or picklist on the Lead and Account objects, or is there something more to it -- but, regardless, you can likely come up with a ProcessBuilder solution that would handle that part, based on the user the Lead was assigned to by the assignment rules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  As far as I know, there is no picklist for territories.  I believe they are text fields, mostly because on occasion I do notice typos.  Thank you so much for your help, I will look into Lead Assignment Rules and go from there.